# How do you set the code signing identity at the project level and not the target level

Tags: ios, xcode

My understanding of the relation between project settings and target settings was that the project settings are high level and may be overridden at the lower level target settings.

I have a project containing more than one target and want to use the same code signing profiles for all of them, therefore I set the code signing identity at the project level and left the identity as 'don't code sign' in the target.

This results in XCode error that things must be signed. Which if "don't code sign" is overriding the project code signing setting would make sense. However there is no option to leave the code signing identity blank in a target - you have to set it to something, which therefore means that the code signing identity that has been set in the project is useless, because it can never be applied because it always has to be overriden by the setting in the target.

Is there some trick to setting the identity in just the project only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Levels" option to see this. [image]

Comment: Using this image, you could select Echo under projects instead of targets and then go to code signing and set it there. This will than set it across all your targets.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said that is what I am already doing " I set the code signing identity at the project level". The problem is I am unable to leave the code signing identity at the target level either empty or set to don't sign. Which means I have to set it to something at the target level - therefore there is no point setting it at the project level because it will be overriden with whatever is set at the target level. That is the whole point of my posting - that XCode insists on you setting something at the target level. To rephrase the question:how do I NOT set something at the target level?

Comment: Did you try choosing the automatic profile selector item in the list?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of what your screen looks like here

Answer (score 3):

At the target level, just select the "Code Signing Identity" option and press delete on your keyboard. It'll automatically use the project-wide setting.